# Cannot get z-index to properly stack video iframe over menu content

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm really stumped on this. I've tried setting a z-index on the iframe element but it keeps getting stacked behind the menu on this page. I've tried setting a lower z-index on just about every part of the navigation menu as well--no luck.

link

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does a parent of the iframe higher in the DOM tree have a z-index lower than the menu? That could cause this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `position: relative` and `z-index: 1` on the .ihcHeader element the video displays fine. This was tested only in Chrome on Mac OS X, so you'll want to test that's true cross-browser.

Basically, the element is not positioned, so z-index isn't working until you position the element. It must have a high stack order intially, so you need to set the z-index of the parent element in the tree to make sure the menu isn't displaying above the video content (or the overlay)